# Debugging referenced DLL in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have multiple projects (lets call one `MyLibrary`) in Visual Studio that contains a lot of nifty functions and classes I use in my other projects. I add a reference to `MyLibrary.dll` directly and not the project itself.

However, I now need to breakpoint my way through something in `MyLibrary` while I run one of my other projects. How can I debug my dll the way I've set up my projects? I know for a fact I've done it earlier with these projects, but since I didn't do anything special, I don't know what's missing.

I've turned off Just-my-code and followed some tips like that, but I haven't gotten into `.pdb's` yet. If I need one to debug another DLL, I would appreciate some information on how to export that from `MyLibrary`.

Comment: You can't, unless you have both the debug symbols and the source code. Without debug symbols, you won't be able to see the other library's methods, symbols, set breakpoints (into IL) etc. Withouth source code you'll only be able to view IL

Comment: I do own the source code, but it seems I don't have any debug symbols.

Comment: Debug symbosl are generated when you build your project. You'll find them in your bin/debug folder

Comment: I found a `pdb` in the `obj` folder. My bin/debug folder does not have one.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to go to the properties of a DLL, and ensure that Copy Local is set to True. Otherwise, Modules won't be able to find the .pdb for your reference

If that doesn't help you can try to rebuild your external library using debug mode, then copy manually both .dll and the .pdb file to the bin of your app.

Comment: I can confirm that Copy Local is set to True for my references.

Comment: you can try to rebuild your external library using debug mode, then copy manually both .dll and the .pdb file to the bin of your app.

Comment: I found `MyLibrary.pdb` in the `obj` folder. It is not automatically copied locally for my other project, but I tried copying it to the `bin` folder with no luck. Still using release for `MyLibrary` though.

Comment: Have you add your dll as a reference to your project? If not - try that one.

Answer (score 0):

While debugging, check in Debug/Modules, if your dll symbols are loaded. If not, let them load. You may be asked to set the folder with pdb files. Pdb contains the symbol used for debugging. It has to be the same version as dll file you are using in your projects. After that you will be able to debug the library.

Comment: I have no `.pdb` for `MyLibrary`, which may be one of the problems here. Debug/Modules says `Binary was not built with debug information`, so symbols are not loaded for that dll.

Comment: @Phil rebuild it with debug information then. You can generate debug symbols even for release DLLs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm sorry to bump you on this, but I have yet to find a way to load the pdb-file with the dll. If I try to load it "manually" in Debug/Modules it will say that `A matching symbol file was not found in this folder` when I select the pdb I have in my `obj` folder. It has the same timestamp as well, so I know it's the matching one. Do you have any further suggestions?

Comment: You have to compile the library you want to debug in debug mode (rather say with symbols generated) and then reload the dll in another project you are debugging. Check if you have Managed (v4.5 or the one you are using) included in debugging options.